# CTRL+ C, variables js

Tags: javascript, copy, ctrl

In my JS script I need to take a variable js extrapolated from a text of the page and copy it to the computer's memory as if I'm copying it pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
Is this possible without any additional libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had similar query and after getting the solution I did something like:

```
var link = "text to be copied",
    linkCopied = false,
    hasError;
  var copyElement = document.createElement('input');
  copyElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  copyElement.setAttribute('value', link);
  copyElement = document.body.appendChild(copyElement);
  copyElement.select();
  try {
    linkCopied = document.execCommand('copy');
  } catch (e) {
    hasError = true;
    $(copyElement).remove();
    prompt("Copy to clipboard:\nSelect, Cmd+C, Enter", link);
  } finally {
    if (!hasError) {
      $(copyElement).remove();
      if (!linkCopied) {
        prompt("Copy to clipboard:\nSelect, Cmd+C, Enter", link);
      }
    }
  }
```

You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).  See the answer by Dean Taylor, as well as the comments on that answer.